# How to transpose n rows in excel into multiple columns

Tags: excel, csv

I have a comma separated file that can be opened in excel. In this file I have the data in two columns like this:

```
Title: A1
Ref: A2
URL Address: A3
Cost Value: A4


Title: B1
Ref: B2
URL Address: B3
Cost Value: B4

Title: C1
Ref: C2
URL Address: C3
Second URL Address: C4 
Cost Value: C5
```

and then the same Lines are repeated with different data obviously.

Now, the issue is that some times there are 4 Lines and some times there are 5 Lines (in case there is "Second URL Address").

I would like to transfer those two columns into multiple columns as shown below:

```
Title   Ref     URL Address     Second URL Address  Cost Value
A1      A2      A3                                  A4
B1      B2      B3                                  B4
C1      C2      C3              C4                  C5
```

I can Import into Excel and then use Text To Columns to split on colon and then use pivot table to split into columns, but the problem is that URL addresses are having colon and sometimes also the Title might have colon.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can do this with VBA.  Use a Dictionary object to create a collection of the relevant lines in your original file, keeping them together by `Title`.  Then output it in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 parts to the question. 1st is to resolve the bit on making sure all cost values go into the 5th row. This can be done with formula.

```
I.e. in cell A6, input the formula
=IF(A5="","",A4) 
and in cell A7, input the formula
=IF(A5="",A4,A5)
```

Drag those formulas to the right, until the final populated column is reached.

After that, paste value row 6 & 7 into rows 4 & 5.

Then delete rows 6 & 7.

This will align your fields

To address the 2nd part of the question, i.e. multi columns

You can the copy the whole thing, and paste as transpose in a new sheet, hence you don't have to delimit it

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can get the format you want with a pivot table.
But lets assume I am wrong and fix the first problem (delimiting).  Someone clever may fix the other part.

You can do a "**Find and Replace**".  Search for ": " and replace with ^
This should work as the colon in a URL will not have a space after it. Hopefully the same for other fields.

Then you can do text->columns using ^ as the delimiter. Now you have 2 columns of data.

As I said, the second part is challenging and can be done but quite messy in excel as you basically want to pivot text and excel doesn't love that.

Comment: Now I think in order to resolve the "Transpose" issue I need to add an additional row of "Second URL Address" with an empty value beneath "URL Address" in order to keep the number of rows (5) all the time which will make the "Transpose" work.

Comment: A transpose of an array two columns wide, and (say) 100 rows, will give you something 100 columns wide and two rows high.  I don't think this is what you want.  You basically need to unstack the data which is non-trivial. You basically want to turn things like Title, URL into their own columns. You can try https://www.xelplus.com/unstack-data-to-multiple-columns/ (once you have your data so every section has the same number of entries - i.e all have the second URL.